# regex help for replacing directories under certain conditions

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to write a regex  to update some registry files for work for an upcoming migration

I have to dynamically update all strings in files where:

1. has a directory path that starts with C:
2. directory does not have "*xyz*" or "*abc*" in the path
3. if the string in the file contains a file [EX *.ext], the only thing that is updated is the directory path and **not** the filename & extension so those are left alone
4. does not replace but instead keeps any appending information in the string [EX: " " " or ")"] that are used to close out the string parameters in the files

I have got it doing 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4. I'm using PowerShell 4.0, recursively checking files in a directory and producing a new file with the changes for each file found in each subdirectory.

The conversion should look like:

```
FROM: setting1="\"C:\\\\this\\\\is\\\\\adirectory\"" 

TO: setting1="\"O:\\\\\New_Directory_Path\""
```

```
FROM: othersetting="\"C:\\\\this\\\\abc\\\\directory""
```

TO: UNCHANGED

```
FROM: thisfile="\"(C:\\\\this\\\\directory\\\\somefile.some_ext)""

TO: thisfile="\"(O:\\\\New_Directory_Path\\\\somefile.some_ext)""
```

I'm at my wits end on this one, this is what I have so far, in terms of regex:

```
gc $file | % {$_ -replace "C:(?!.*abc.*)(?!.*xyz.*)(?!.*\..*).*","O:\\\\New_Directory_Path\"} | out-file "$filePath\$newFileName"
```

Hoping someone on here can lend a hand. Also, this is my first time posting on here, sorry for not putting my code in tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this pattern
Edited:

```
C:(?!.*(abc|xyz)).*?(?=[^\\]+\.[^\\]+|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/217)

Comment: Not sure if the ops strings have leading characters before the C ie `"\"(C`

Comment: well, I based it on the OP's attempt. but you're right, `^` could be omitted.

Comment: wow awesome thanks. Can someone upvote him for me, I need 15 rep points to do that :\. Just one edit and it worked, `C:(?!.*(abc|xyz)).*?(?=[^\\]+\.[^\\]+|$)` instead of `^C:(?!.*(abc|xyz)).*?(?=[^\\]+\.[^\\]+|$)`